# Using pointers with parent class type triggers parent class destructor rather than child class destructor

Tags: c++, destructor

I am struggling a bit with the details of using pointers with parent classes as a type, when I want to actually trigger the destructor of child classes. This is my (very simplified version) inheritance structure:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Parent {
  public:
    ~Parent() { std::cout << "Parent destructor" << std::endl; }
};

class ChildA: public Parent {
  public:
    ~ChildA() { std::cout << "ChildA destructor" << std::endl; }
};

class ChildB: public Parent {
  public:
    ~ChildB() { std::cout << "ChildB destructor" << std::endl; }
};
```

Now, in my main function, I first create an object of `ChildA`, then destroy it and create an object of `ChildB`, while using the same pointer to reference to these objects. To do so, I am using `Parent` as the type of the pointer (again, very simplified version of a real world scenario).

```cpp
int main() {
  Parent* myObj;
  myObj = new ChildA();
  delete myObj;
  myObj = new ChildB();
  delete myObj;

  return 0;
}
```

My issue with this is, that this is calling the destructor of the parent class, which always results in printing `"Parent destructor"` to standard out, rather than `"ChildA destructor"` and `"ChildB destructor"`. I assumed that it would implicitly call the destructor of the actual (child) class. So my question is, how can I trigger the destructor of the child class when I want to destroy the object and still refer to them with a pointe that uses their parent class as a type?

Comment: Use `virtual` destructors.

Comment: If a program deletes an object of a derived type through a pointer to a base type, the base type **must** have a virtual destructor. If it doesn't, the behavior of the program is undefined.